# ReferenceError: org is not defined , when trying to start the composer or deploy the network on playground?? Not able to find the cause

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created a business network named chemicalnetwork. I created the bna file and tried deploying it according to the instructions in composer documentation: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

I am not able to do composer network start. It is giving following error:

> Starting business network definition. This may take a minute... Error:
>   Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from
>   any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2
>   UNKNOWN: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: org is not
>   defined

I am not able to understand which org this is talking about.

Same error pops when I deploy on the composer playground

I tried all the solutions present and error messages are changing constantly. I even turned down the version from 0.20 to 0.19 used the teardown process and redoing all the steps multiple times

I just want this to be successful as I have to create rest server next

Comment: It could be an error from your chaincode. Maybe you are using or passing a variable called `org` that is not defined. Check the uses of the namespace into your code

Comment: Check if your namespace are correct everywhere in the logic, model and acl.